# problem updating dropdownlist

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a problem while updating changing the item in dropdownlist.

I have a dropdownlist which is populated in code behind file.

Here is the code:

```
departmentComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT DepartmentID, Department FROM Departments", conn);
conn.Open();
reader = departmentComm.ExecuteReader();
// Populate the list of categories
departmentList.DataSource = reader;
departmentList.DataValueField = "DepartmentID";
departmentList.DataTextField = "Department";
departmentList.DataBind();
// Close the reader
reader.Close();
```

I select one value from this list and saves it in my employee table. Now let's suppose I want to update this value in employee table.

Now my question is, how can I pull this value in dropdownlist and show it?

Comment: What language? What GUI framework? What type of control? There isn't enough information given here to answer this question.

Comment: i m working on c#. i just want to know how can i retrieve the value in dropdownlist using my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just van to get the selected department id:

```
departmentList.SelectedValue
```

gives you the id

If you embedded the dropdown in a datagrid you will need to update the database using a DataAdapter and call its Update method.

If you need more specifics you need to give more details.

Comment: SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Department FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID", connection); this gives me department value now how can i use this value as selected value in dropdownlist. if i use departmentList.SelectedItem.Text = reader["Department"].ToString(); it although gives changes the selcted value in dropdownlist but the since i dont know the index of this value, the value changes the value of last index selected. e.g if the index of last selected item was 0 then it selected value will  use index 0

Comment: Read more carefully: Use SelectedValue not SelectedItem.Text! That will give you the ID. You do not want the index you want to use the ID.